# Docker -- How To Connect Services Together Using Docker Compose With ZeroMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, zeromq

I have a docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  bifrost:
    image: ivorytoast3853/bifrost
    container_name: bifrost-app
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"

  thor:
    image: ivorytoast3853/thor
    container_name: thor-app
    ports:
      - "8085:8084"

  loki:
    image: ivorytoast3853/loki
    container_name: loki-app
    ports:
      - "8086:8084"
```

Which is meant to test a ZeroMQ app.

- Bifrost: Broker
- Thor: Server
- Loki: Client

I am using the exact code from ZeroMQ's start guide (and when I start it locally -- without Docker it ***works (Loki sends messages to Thor through the Bifrost)***).
For reference, the 3 files are:

**LOKI**

```
try (ZContext context = new ZContext()) {
     ZMQ.Socket requester = context.createSocket(SocketType.REQ);
     boolean didConnect = requester.connect("tcp://0.0.0.0:5559");

     log.info("Loki connected to the bifrost: " + didConnect);
     for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr < 10; request_nbr++) {
          requester.send("One", 0);
          String reply = requester.recvStr(0);
          System.out.println("Received reply " + request_nbr + " [" + reply + "]");
     }
}
```

**Thor**

```
try (ZContext context = new ZContext()) {
     ZMQ.Socket responder = context.createSocket(SocketType.REP);
     boolean didConnect = responder.connect("tcp://0.0.0.0:5560");

     log.info("Thor connected to the bifrost: " + didConnect);
     while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
          String string = responder.recvStr(0);
          System.out.printf("Received request: [%s]\n", string);

          try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }

          responder.send("You sent me: " + string);
     }
}
```

**Bifrost**

```
while (true) {
     try (ZContext context = new ZContext()) {
          ZMQ.Socket frontend = context.createSocket(SocketType.ROUTER);
          ZMQ.Socket backend = context.createSocket(SocketType.DEALER);
          frontend.bind("tcp://*:5559");
          backend.bind("tcp://*:5560");

          log.info("Started Bifrost to connect Loki and Thor");

          ZMQ.Poller items = context.createPoller(2);
          items.register(frontend, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
          items.register(backend, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);

          boolean more = false;
          byte[] message;

          while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
               items.poll();

               if (items.pollin(0)) {
                    while (true) {
                         message = frontend.recv(0);
                         more = frontend.hasReceiveMore();

                         backend.send(message, more ? ZMQ.SNDMORE : 0);
                         if (!more) {
                              break;
                         }
                    }
                }
                if (items.pollin(1)) {
                     while (true) {
                          message = backend.recv(0);
                          more = backend.hasReceiveMore();
                          frontend.send(message, more ? ZMQ.SNDMORE : 0);
                          if (!more) {
                            break;
                          }
                     }
                }
          }
     }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the Docker compose file? I know Docker compose creates a network automatically...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was not internalizing fundamental ideas of docker and containers as a whole.

**The Problem**

- I was trying to connect to: `"tcp://0.0.0.0:5560"` from Loki/Thor to Bifrost.

**Why is that a problem?**

It is a problem because unlike starting all 3 spring boot applications on the same computer (with the same IP), I am starting each spring application in its OWN docker container -- which has its OWN UNIQUE IP. Therefore, I cannot say to Loki/Thor to "on this computer (IP), connect to Bifrost." -- since Bifrost lies on a completely separate IP address.

**How did I fix it:**

I changed the docker-compose file for Bifrost to contain a network alias:

```
    image: ivorytoast3853/bifrost
    container_name: bifrost-app
    networks:
      my-net:
        aliases:
          - queue
```

All this does is allow me to say, "if I give you the hostname of "queue", please connect to the IP address of the container that the Bifrost application is found on."

Then, all I had to do is change the host:port string in Loki and Thor to reflect the following:

`responder.connect("tcp://queue:5560");`

Hope this helps anyone who comes across a similar issue (or lack of understanding in my case)

Comment: Without changing the `docker-compose.yml` file, you can use the service names `bifrost`, `thor`, and `loki` as host names.  (You might even remove the `container_name:` setting to simplify things slightly, Compose can pick its own.)